# Having to type "bundle exec" before rake tasks now after Rails upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I really like that `Spring` is included in the Rails standard Gemfile now. I have a new project I started from scratch where I can just type:

```
rake <my rake task>
```

and it's run under Spring so that the whole environment doesn't have to load again.

However, I recently upgraded a project from `v3.2` to `v4.2.3`, and I get an error. It only works if I do:

bundle exec rake

How can I get this upgraded project to run under spring again?

Comment: Now I have errors that say to get rid of the rails binstubs. Confusing.

Comment: this is a warning just to regenerate binstubs in different format which is normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have system wide and application specific gem sets that conflict each other. Simply remove system wide gems and use Bundler special feature. Bundler binstubs helps to avoid prepend *bundle exec* every time:

```
gem uninstall rake
bundle install --binstubs
./bin/rake
```

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs

> Assuming the binstubs for a project are in the local bin/ directory,
>   you can even go a step further to add the directory to shell $PATH so
>   that rspec can be invoked without the bin/ prefix:

```
export PATH="./bin:$PATH"
rake
```